# Always getting 254 from serial port

Tags: c#, c++, arduino

I am handing a byte array into my bluesmirf uno on an arduino board through a windows forms application. I am able to read the signal from the bluetooth and print it out via serial but the output is always 254 and I have no idea why.

Below is the C++ code.

```
const int led = 8;
int incomingByte = 0;
#define RxD 10
#define TxD 11

#include <hmi.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(RxD, TxD); // RX pin, TX pin

void setup() {
 pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(RxD, INPUT);
 pinMode(TxD, OUTPUT);
 Serial.begin(9600); 
 mySerial.begin(11520); 
}

void loop() {
  incomingByte = mySerial.read();
  if(incomingByte > 0){
   Serial.println("Here is: ");
    Serial.println(incomingByte);
    digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
   }
}
```

And here is the relevant c# code.

```
        int MyInt = 1;

        byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(MyInt);
        serialPort1.Write(b, 0, 4);
```

I am able to get the code to output 248 with the c# code:

```
serialPort1.Write(new Byte[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 0 , 4);
```

and 192 from

```
byte[] b = { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
serialPort1.Write(b, 0, 7);
```

But I have no idea why, the number that is returned seems to be based on the number of elements passed in the byte array regardless of what is actually in the array.

Comment: How many bits is your word size for the serial port?

Comment: I have no idea, how would I go about checking that? That said since it's 254 i'd imagine it's 8.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, I've never worked with Arduinos but it sounds like you've got a dodgy connection somewhere that means that your serial link is throwing out it's maximum value (2^8 less 2 parity bits) but I could be wrong.

Comment: 11520 is not a sensible baudrate selection, consider 115200 instead.

Comment: `254 ` is `0b11111110`, `248` is `11111000` and `192` is `11000000`. Looks like baudrate problem to me. Are you sure baudrates match on both sides? 11520 looks like a typo. And 115200 isn't considered reliable on software serial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed randomly while I was just hammering at it.

I assume the fix to the issue was that I had the baud rate set at 11520 instead of 115200 as Gre_Gor said.

Answer (score 1):

You should try lower baud rates.  SoftwareSerial uses lot of CPU and it is possible that microcontroller just can not handle all data.

Refs: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/30117/32059, http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=96271.0 and and http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=140299.msg1063344#msg1063344